# Move Nominatim data from one system to another system

Tags: nominatim

We have a Ubantu 14 server which is running the Nominatim service with postgres database.

Now we are tring to upgrade the Ubantu to latest, not able to upgrade because the postgres is installed separate, not used the "apt-get" which is not allowing to upgrade.

So we are planning to create new VM with Ubantu 16 and install postgres from apt-get.

Question is can i move the Nominatim database to new server? and How?